# Duplicate NS in SOAP Message

Tags: java, xml, soap, namespaces, websphere

Ive got a problem with my xml SOAP message - using java 1.8, Websphere 8.5.5.17, for generating class from wsdl Ive used jaxws-maven-plugin.

When I received SOAP message via WAS to my Java application, something duplicate my ns3 prefix (sometimes another), and unmarshaling to type Object is not work :(

```
        <ns3:document xmlns:ns4="http://service.gggg.com/common/CommonMessage/v01" xmlns:ns3="http://service.gggg.com/RDS/datamodel/LAA/common/v01">
              <ns3:outputChannels>
              <ns3:archiveType>None</ns3:archiveType>
              <ns3:publishingType>Signature</ns3:publishingType>
              <ns3:printType>None</ns3:printType></ns3:document>
```

ns3 prefix is correctly defined upper and element "document" is anyType. The problem is in the inner atribute of document element -> the second definiton of **xmlns:ns3**, when I overide it manualy together with ns of childs **it works**.

```
            <ns3:document xmlns:ns4="http://service.gggg.com/common/CommonMessage/v01" xmlns:ns9="http://service.gggg.com/RDS/datamodel/LAA/common/v01">
              <ns9:outputChannels>
              <ns9:archiveType>None</ns9:archiveType>
              <ns9:publishingType>Signature</ns9:publishingType>
              <ns9:printType>None</ns9:printType></ns3:document>
```

Ive just tried jaxb NamespacePrefixMapper, namespaces set in jaxb bindings, manualy overiding in Interceptor SOAPElement, add prefix namespace in package-info.java and a lot lot lot of more but without happy end :(

maven

```
 <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsimport</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <genJWS>false</genJWS>
                        <extension>true</extension>
                        <wsdlFiles>
                            <wsdlFile>
                                ${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/ServiceWSDL.wsdl
                            </wsdlFile> 
                        </wsdlFiles>
                        <target>2.0</target>
                        <xadditionalHeaders>true</xadditionalHeaders>
                        <bindingFiles>
                            <bindingFile>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/jaxb/bindings.xml</bindingFile>
                            <bindingFile>${project.basedir}/src/jaxws/binding.xml</bindingFile>
                        </bindingFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

binding.xml

```
<jaxws:bindings xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws">
<jaxws:enableWrapperStyle>false</jaxws:enableWrapperStyle></jaxws:bindings>
```

bindings.xml

```
<jaxb:bindings version="2.0" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
           xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc">
<jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="false" fixedAttributeAsConstantProperty="true"
                         choiceContentProperty="true"/>
</jaxb:bindings></jaxb:bindings>
```

Can someone help me ?

THX!

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following the point within the invocation chain here where the problem is first appearing.   Are you saying the SOAP client is sending an incorrect payload (with the xmlns:ns3 prefix incorrectly overloaded), and you want to find a way to creatively "fix" it via unmarshalling?    Or are you saying the JAXB-etc. classes you're generating via wsimport with the jaxws-maven-plugin were responsible for producing this (incorrect) payload somehow?